# ASP.NET login control, login status change URL for login

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have a question about object "Login Status " on `ASP.NET`

When I'm logged out, I can click "access" and it link to `login.aspx`. I have the login page of my web site in another web page (different name).

How can I change this link ? 
In properties of `LoginStatus`, there is `LoginOutUrl`, but there isn't log in URL.

How can I solve this? Will I modify my login page into login.aspx or can I change this link?

Comment: Solve : create login.aspx and on the load set a Response.Redirect with the url that i want.

Comment: You should post an answer to your question (with more detail) instead of just a comment.

Comment: I can't because my account is blocked ...

Answer (score 0):

For the knowledgement about how to solve the problem (my question over) .

> - Create a new web page called "login.aspx"  Pay attention to use exactly that name because when you will log off with your login
>     status, you will be re direct on login.aspx
> - At the page load of "login.aspx", put a redirect to your favorite destination page url

I know that it is a basic method but when i was at start with asp.net , it wasn't so easy as now .